# Use stored data from flamingo and contact form 7 and display it in checkout page fields

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I want to display some of the values inserted by the users (using contact form 7) in some checkout fields in the checkout page can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use CRM Entries plugin. To fetch data from that plugin you can do this.
fetch all form data of particular user. (lead_id will be id of user)

```
global $wpdb;
$results = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM wp_vxcf_leads_detail WHERE lead_id= '26'");
        
        foreach($results as $row){   
            echo $row->name;
            echo $row->value;
        }
```

Comment: where this code should be placed? and can you give me a plugin name so I can download it? I am still new to WordPress so if u can explain more it would be great

Comment: Hi @HypertextAssassin the plugin name is "CRM ENTRIES" it stores and displays forms data. I don't know where exactly you want to show the fields value, may be in any of woocommerce template file?

Comment: in fields inside the checkout page

Comment: and i cannot find the plugin ur talking about if u can send me a link

Comment: Sure.
https://wordpress.org/plugins/contact-form-entries/

Comment: for use in checkout page, you need to put code in woocommerce template for checkout.
woocommerce/templates/checkout/form-checkout.php
you can override plugin template in your theme. check this link
https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/256088/how-to-override-woocommerce-template-files